# How to Dynamically change (Remove or Add) formoptions:{elmprefix:"*"}

Tags: jqgrid

I'm controlling the `colProp` required value in the `beforeShowForm` function and its working fine. My problem is the `formoptions:{elmprefix:"*"}` does not take effect.
Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to do it?
My code snippet is this

```js
$grid2.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
    { edit:true, add:true, del:true, search:false, view:true, cloneToTop:true},
    { // edit options  
        beforeShowForm: function(form) {   
            $("#list").setColProp('Done_Date',
                {editrules:{required:true}, formoptions:{elmprefix:"*"}});
            $("#list").setColProp('Outcome',
                {editrules:{required:true}, formoptions:{elmprefix:"*"}});      
        },     
        editCaption:"Edit Record",
        edittext:"Edit",
        closeOnEscape:true,
        savekey: [true,13],
        errorTextFormat:commonError,
        width:"550",
        reloadAfterSubmit:true,
        bottominfo:"Fields marked with (*) are required",
        top:"60",
        left:"70",
        closeAfterEdit:false
    },
```

Thanks in advance
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The you should use [beforeInitData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) instead of `beforeShowForm` to be able to change `elmprefix` setting on the fly during creating of the form. Additionally you should use [recreateForm: true](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) property.

I would recommend you to read [the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/147495) which describes how to format the code inside of the question.

Comment: Thanks Oleg for the answer and the guidance. Its appreciated.